# MongoDB design/refactoring

Tags: mongodb, refactoring

I have a project that has (ta-daaa) scope-crept on me.

What started as a simple app to track calibrated tools (each tool has a yearly rotation cycle to check calibration) has turned into inventory tracking too.

So my current model has some required fields and an embedded doc of calibrations:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("51b0d94c3f72fb89c9000014"),
  barcode: "H-131887",
  calibrations: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("51b0d94c3f72fb89c9000015"),
      cal_date: ISODate("2013-07-03T16:04:57.893Z"),
      cal_date_due: ISODate("2013-07-03T16:04:57.894Z"),
      ats_in: ISODate("2013-06-01T16:04:57.895Z"),
      ats_out: ISODate("2013-06-06T16:04:57.897Z")
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("51b0e6053f72fbb27900001b"),
      cal_date: ISODate("2013-06-13T00:00:00Z"),
      cal_date_due: ISODate("2014-06-13T00:00:00Z"),
      ats_in: ISODate("2013-06-06T00:00:00Z"),
      ats_out: ISODate("2013-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
      updated_at: ISODate("2013-07-09T14:44:31.113Z"),
      created_at: ISODate("2013-06-06T19:41:57.770Z")
    }
  ],
  created_at: ISODate("2013-06-06T18:47:40.481Z"),
  creator_id: ObjectId("5170547c791e4b1a16000001"),
  description: "",
  group: "engine",
  location: "Cabinet 1",
  maker: "MITUTOYO",
  model: "2046S",
  serial: "QEL228",
  status: "In",
  tool: "Dial Indicator",
  updated_at: ISODate("2013-07-09T14:44:31.103Z")
}
```

What would be the best way to allow non-calibrated tools in this schema where Barcode/Serial are not required for those tools? Also, they won't have calibration dates, so my current table that lists the tool and most recent calibration date won't be happy returning nil calibrations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely that you will need to refactor your database schema.

MongoDB is supposed to work with heterogeneous data. That means not all documents in the same collection need to have the same fields. It is no problem at all for MongoDB when some documents have fields and even sub-documents regarding calibration information and some have not.

When you have a find-query which is not supposed to return documents which don't have calibration information, you can just add the find-condition `calibrations: { $exists: true }` and only return those documents where the calibration field exists. But even a query like `find({"calibrations.cal_date_due":{$lt:ISODate()})` will not choke on documents which don't have a field `calibrations` and thus no `calibrations.cal_date_due` either. It will just skip these documents silently.

Comment: You may want to look at using sparse indexes for any field that lives in a subset of documents and which needs to be queries against. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#sparse-indexes

Comment: indeed! sparse are vey useful! updating the link:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/